# Blender does not save openexr images in grayscale

Tags: cycles-render-engine, color, .exr

I wish to save rendered images in linear color space, and in floating point format. Also, I am only interested in total amount of light captured, not in its RGB components, therefore I have it set to BW, as such:

[image: Output options in blender]

When saving the image, I get a similar panel, with mostly the same options, except it doesn't have the BW option:

[image]

Note also that just in case, I chose to override the color management option, and insist that I want it in linear space.

The resulting image, as loaded in Matlab by its `exrread` function, is not grayscale, but an RGB image. Furthermore, while the resulting image appears to be in linear space (based on some simple math and the fact I know the facet and light orientations), the color channels are not the same, but differ based on what I assume is noise. The object is the default cube with diffuse BSDF with a color that is 80% white (zero saturation, 0.8 value).

When I increase the quality of the render, either by reducing the noise, and/or by increasing the number of ray samples per pixel, the difference between the colour channels remains the same.

If I change the colour in the diffuse BSDF to something non-gray, the resulting image is coloured, i.e. the color channels differ in the way one would expect for an RGB render.

I realise this is a very easy problem to deal with, all I need to do is mix the channels myself at the end, but nonetheless it would be more convenient if blender just did it for me.

As a final note, the light source is a sun with pure white coloured light. I am using the cycles render engine.

Comment: Maybe you can work around it by using the compositor. Set up a few *File Output* nodes with pre defined desired file settings, use a an *RGB to BW* node to explicitly get a black and white image. One benefit of this is a certain degree of automation on file save.

Comment: Note that you do not get the amount of light 'captured'. You get the amount of light reflected by the shader. This is not right if you want to calculate the amount of light received by the scene. If you set the material to completely white, you will get different secondary bounces since it will reflect more back to the scene. Caustics is also not calculated well in Cycles, so if you are trying to do radiance calculations with Blender, it will have problems. But hey, what doesn't?.. EXR always saves linear, and ignores CM completely. You can do some maths in compositing before output to EXR.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys EXR ignores color management, but not the color mode settings if you choose RGB or RGBA - you get different files, one without and one with alpha channel. And EXR files can have a greyscale channel Y, which GIMP uses for example (Photoshop does not, or at least I don't know how). And while the BW option for a PNG file saves a greyscale image even when the render is colored, this does not work with EXR, there is no conversion, it will be saved as RGBA. So even if EXR ignores CM, I would expect Blender to convert the image to linear greyscale and save it in the Y channel.

Comment: I think I am going to use the solution proposed by @DuarteFarrajotaRamos and added a RGB to BW node in the compositor. The saved .exr still has 3 channels, but they're all the same. For my purposes, this is good enough. I didn't know about the compositor.

Comment: As for @MartynasŽiemys's comment, I meant the actual amount of light captured by the light sensor, I am not doing anything that complicated. Sorry for the unclear term.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann, Matlab's exrread says there's no Y channel in the image.
This is the case even if I use the compositor to convert to grayscale. I get an exr file with RGB data, where all channels are the same. This is good enough for me, but just letting you know.

Comment: @Sirplentifus I know there is no Y channel. I said that since Blender offers the BW option in the _Output Properties_, I would expect it to convert to greyscale and save the data in the Y channel. I did not say it does.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Ah, yes I misread your comment. Thanks

Comment: This could be considered a bug and reported.